# Bitbucket pipeline - possibility to merge one branch to another

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I have a repository with two branches: **master** and **Dev** and I want to configure that pipline in such a way that when I push code to **Dev** branch and code build was successfull, the **Dev** was merged to **master**. Unfortunatly I can't find any information about merge in bitbucket piplines [docs](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/configure-bitbucket-pipelines-yml-792298910.html#Configurebitbucket-pipelines.yml-ci_branchesbranches(optional)).

That's my yml file:

```
pipelines:
  branches:
    Dev:
      - step:
          script:
            - ant deployCodeCheckOnly -Dsf.username=$SF_USERNAME -Dsf.password=$SF_PASSWORD
```

Could somebody help me with that case? If it possible?

--Edit

I try to change script as sugest:

```
pipelines:
  branches:
    Dev:
      - step:
          script:
            - ant deployCodeCheckOnly -Dsf.username=$SF_USERNAME -Dsf.password=$SF_PASSWORD
            - git remote -v
            - git fetch
            - git checkout master
            - git merge Dev
            - git push -v --tags origin master:master
```

Result:

```
git remote -v
+ git remote -v
origin  git@bitbucket.org:repository/project.git (fetch)
origin  git@bitbucket.org:repository/project.git (push)

git fetch origin
+ git fetch origin
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address ..... to the list of known hosts.
```

And error:

```
+ git checkout master
error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

--Solution

```
  Dev:
       - step:
           script:
            - ant deployCodeCheckOnly -Dsf.username=$SF_USERNAME Dsf.password=$SF_PASSWORD
             - git fetch
             - git checkout -b master
             - git merge Dev
             - git push -v --tags origin master:master
```

Comment: The reason that `git checkout master` failed with the `pathspec` error, but `git checkout -b master` succeeded, is because Bitbucket Pipelines only pulls the branch being built down to the build agent running the pipeline.  There is no `master` branch in its repo clone, so you have to create it.  And then indicate that your push should go to the upstream `origin master`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the “script” section of the YAML configuration, you can do more or less anything you can do at the shell, so (although I’ve never tried it) don’t see a reason why this shouldn’t be possible.

In other words, you’d have to:

- Switch the branch to `master`
- Merge dev (optionally, using the predefined `BITBUCKET_COMMIT` environment variable, which identifies your `dev` commit)
- Commit to `master` (and probably also push)

As `git` is available in `script`, you can use normal git commands and do not need anything specific to Bb Pipelines, like so:

```
 script:
    - git fetch
    - git checkout -b master
    - git merge Dev
    - git push -v --tags origin master:master
```

To make sure this is only done when your Ant job is successful, you should make sure that in case of an error you’ll get a non-zero exit status (which, I assume, is Ant’s default behaviour).

Comment: I simplified things a bit. Your branch `master` is not automatically present, but you have to `git fetch` first (the remote is defined, *but*: you have to insert a deployment key, as otherwise you are not allowed to fetch from the remote) before you can `git checkout master`.

Comment: I try many things. Please look again of my edit, and advice me how the pipline should look. Thanks.

Comment: One more thing: 'git branch' retrieves:
Dev and remotes/origin/Dev

Comment: Ok. I found the solution. Please look on it, and confirm if it's a good way to do that.

Comment: I can’t tell if it’s a good solution, as I never tried to do that myself. But if it works for you, it can’t be too bad ;-) [And it looks pretty straightforward, so I don’t see anything to worry about.]

Answer (score 13):

I was facing the same issue, but wanted to use pull requests instead of simple git merge. So I ended up utilising bitbucket API for the job:

1. Create "App password"
   --
   Create "App password" so you don't have to push your own credentials to pipelines
   (bitbucket settings -> app passwords)

[image: bitbucket app password]

2. Set environment variables for pipelines
   --

   - BB_USER = your username
   - BB_PASSWORD = app password
3. Create bash script
   --
   I have a bash script that creates pull request from `$BITBUCKET_BRANCH` and merge it immediately

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Exit immediately if a any command exits with a non-zero status
# e.g. pull-request merge fails because of conflict
set -e

# Set destination branch
DEST_BRANCH=$1

# Create new pull request and get its ID
echo "Creating PR: $BITBUCKET_BRANCH -> $DEST_BRANCH"
PR_ID=`curl -X POST https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/$BITBUCKET_REPO_OWNER/$BITBUCKET_REPO_SLUG/pullrequests \
  --fail --show-error --silent \
  --user $BB_USER:$BB_PASSWORD \
  -H 'content-type: application/json' \
  -d '{
    "title": "Automerger: '$BITBUCKET_BRANCH' -> '$DEST_BRANCH'",
    "description": "Automatic PR from pipelines",
    "state": "OPEN",
    "destination": {
      "branch": {
              "name": "'$DEST_BRANCH'"
          }
    },
    "source": {
      "branch": {
              "name": "'$BITBUCKET_BRANCH'"
          }
    }
  }' \
  | sed -E "s/.*\"id\": ([0-9]+).*/\1/g"`

# Merge PR
echo "Merging PR: $PR_ID"
curl -X POST https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/$BITBUCKET_REPO_OWNER/$BITBUCKET_REPO_SLUG/pullrequests/$PR_ID/merge \
  --fail --show-error --silent \
  --user $BB_USER:$BB_PASSWORD \
  -H 'content-type: application/json' \
  -d '{
    "close_source_branch": false,
    "merge_strategy": "merge_commit"
  }'
```

- usage: `./merge.sh DESTINATION_BRANCH`
- see [pipelines environment variables documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/environment-variables-794502608.html) to understand better used variables
- see [bitbucket API docs](https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/repositories/%7Busername%7D/%7Brepo_slug%7D/pullrequests) for more info about used API

4. Finally in pipelines
   --
   just call the script:

```
Dev:
       - step:
           script:
            - chmod +x ./merge.sh
            - ./merge.sh master
```

### Benefits:

- Pipeline will fail if there is conflict (if you want it to fail)
- better control of what's happening