# How to successfully create a merged pull request through BitBucket API?

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-api, bitbucket-cloud

For my app I need to be able to create already merged pull requests through BitBucket API.

According to their [documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/bitbucket/rest/api-group-pullrequests/#api-repositories-workspace-repo-slug-pullrequests-post), all I need to specify is the `state` parameter as `MERGED`, however this doesn't seem to work.

When sending a request to that endpoint, with a body like this:

```json
{
  "title": "Merged pull request",
  "source":{
      "branch":{
          "name": "branchname"
      }
  },
  "state": "MERGED"
}
```

the API ends up creating a branch with an `OPEN` state. I've also tried specifying a `merge_commit` as hinted [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/pullrequests-resource-423626332.html?focusedCommentId=734071465) in some older documentation, however it ended in the same way.

Another option that I tried was creating an open pull request and then updating its state to `MERGED` both with and without specifying a `merge_commit`, however it didn't do anything, the API replied with a pull request with no changes.

Searching for this or related issues on the internet brought nothing but some duplicate documentation and parts of source code (defining the structure of a pull request) of tools that interact with BitBucket API, and lastly [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43954327/bitbucket-pipeline-possibility-to-merge-one-branch-to-another) which ended up not being the question nor the answer that I was looking for.

Is there some *correct* way to create an already merged pull request with BitBucket API?